# 2 finger scroll not working on ASUS GL752VW

Tags: mouse, touchpad, asus, multi-touch, synaptics

I recently got the Asus ROG GL752VW and it came with Windows 10 and all was working perfectly.

I then installed Ubuntu 16.04 but the fans constantly were running on full speed and the speed controller wasnt working for me. The problem i'm having with 14.04 is the 2 finger scroll that worked perfectly on windows 10 and the screen brightness function!

I've tried installing and running synclient but i keep getting a drivers error.

This is my result when I use the `xinput list`

```
    alffi@alffi-GL752VW:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN1000:00 04F3:0401                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam                      id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Thank you for any help in advance, I never realised how much I would miss the 2 finger scrolling! I've tried a few other answers that have been suggested for similar errors on this website but I've had no success!

Comment: Does 2-finger scroll work on 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

For the fan problem: I had success on that department by installing NVIDIA's drivers. I would not recommend mindlessly installing those without consulting someone who knows their stuff. Either way, the default driver just didn't support the laptop well enough.

I do think most of your issues are due to drivers being incompatible, not installed or simply non-existent.